# PHP Templates in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: php, aptana

I was using Eclipse PDT for a time, but I decided to move to Aptana 3 for performance questions. So far, so good, the Aptana 3 is great, but I missing some features of Eclipse, mainly the PHP Templates.

I see the AS3 have this feature to PyDev, so, WHY there is no PHP Templates?! Sincerely, I can't understand! Furthermore, even if I decide to create some snippets, the snippets creation in AS3 is very difficult and boring...

So, my question is: anyone knows how enable the PHP Templates in Aptana Studio 3?

Comment: See http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2076